# LoadBalancer with ApacheProxy on ESXi VMs

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, vmware-esxi, load-balancing

I'm trying to build a Load Balanacer using Apache's mod_balancer. In this project are involved 1NAS Server 2 ESXi Servers(Here I have all of my Workers running on Internal Network), 1PhysicalServer which acts as Proxy. My problem is that the workers should be able to access the Internet but should not be exposed. I'm quite newbie in Netwoks and maybe the workaround what I've been deploying is not the best one. How can I have internet access on workers if you take in consideration the following structure
[image]

If somebody has a good tip or a tutorial what I could follow I would really appreciate if would share with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

configure your router/firewall to [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT) the outgoing traffic from 192.168.123.124 and .125 and allow them to communicate with the internet resources. ideally - allow them only to talk with limited range of hosts or at least ports - so in case workers get compromised somehow scope of the damage is limited.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Can you please explain a bit deeper your workaround

Comment: @fefe how exactly should i explain? setting up the NAT on your router depends on the type of appliance you have - it'll be different for cisco, different for linux or bsd based soft-routers.

Comment: okay if I understood good I should setup on each side(ESXi) a Virtual Machine as Router-Gateway. If that would be the case than I need 2 Public Static IP's what actually I do not have.

Comment: you can set up NAT/packet forwarding on VM1/machine exposed to the internet and multihome it. although that might not be the best from the security point of view.

Comment: thanks you for your help! I'm still struggling with it but I marked as accepted. Would have sense to install a separate vm router appliance like pfsense or Vyatta?

Comment: yes - if you have 'spare' ip address to assign it to vyatta - sure, but maybe you can have nat functionality on your existing router that you included on the picture?